# MySQL SUM when using GROUP BY not working

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sum

Let's say we have this table:

```
Symbol | Size
A      | 12
B      | 5
A      | 3
A      | 6
B      | 8
```

And we want a view like this:

```
Symbol | Size
A      | 21
B      | 13
```

So we use this:

```
Select Symbol, sum(Size) from table group by Symbol order by Symbol ASC
```

But instead we get this:

```
Symbol | Size
A      | 12
B      | 5
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Are those the real columns you're using in your test?  If so, what are their datatypes?

Comment: this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Is that the full table?  The only significant gotcha in group functions are related to nulls in columns, can't see how here, but I think a full dump of the data is required to get a correct answer

Comment: No, that's not all, they are about 45 column in the table and 3000+ rows... Actually I have this problem in 2 tables, one of them does contain NULL, although in another table I used this and had NULL, I had no problem, so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: Symbol is string but which kind: varchar, char, text? Add the output of `desc table1` or `show create table table1` in you question. And add some real values of Symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that somewhere in the `Select` commands that leaded to the Un-SUMable table instead of a `left join` there was a simple `join`.Although I still don't get why that should mess up the calculation, I changed that and now it works... I'm sorry I couldn't upload the whole thing...

Comment: Please provide the query. I have the same problem. I might have found solution by the time you are posting query, but it might help others

Comment: It's been almost 8 years, but if I remember correctly I was doing a `sum` on two joined tables and changing the `join` to a `left join` fixed it. I would suggest you follow the suggestion by Roee Adler to see if everything else is ok.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You are doing it right, you should expect the correct results. Could you please supply more information about the DB you are using, additional schemas, etc?

Maybe you have some unique index on Symbol?

Try to execute the following to "sanity-test" your system:

```
SELECT SUM(Size) FROM table
```

Should result in 34

```
SELECT Symbol, Count(*) FROM table GROUP BY Symbol
```

Should results in 3 and 2

If both of the above work perfectly as you noted, please try:

```
SELECT Symbol, Count(*), Sum(Size) FROM table GROUP BY Symbol
```

This is your code, with the additions of Count(*) and without the ORDER BY clause. If that does not work after the two above do, I'm really puzzled...

Comment: Nope, nothing unique or special. simple database table of MySQL 5.1

Comment: Both work perfectly, but to be honest if I try to use the select Symbol, sum(Size) from table group by Symbol order by Symbol ASC on a small table it does work also, the problem is when I try to use it on something big (could the size be the problem? Or maybe if there are NULL values?)