# Mysql multiple SUM in one query - novice

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I am counting clicks per category of ads. I am curently passing category to function, I have 10 cats, so I am calling this function 10 times to get number of clicks for each category. So i am trying to figure out is it possible to do in one query. Just started with mysql This is my code:

```
SELECT SUM(clicks) AS 'clicks' FROM wp_cb_ads_manager WHERE category = '.$cat.'
```

and this gives me

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [clicks] => 11 ) )
```

Is it possible to do this on one query, so to retrieve SUM per each category in array. Here is the screen of how 2 tables looks like:

http://awesomescreenshot.com/00018kly6d
http://awesomescreenshot.com/06418kltcc

In first i keep list of categories, and in second I keep ads where one field is used to check in which category is ad.

Comment: A bit unclear, you may want to add the schema to your question instead of linking to external images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your screenshots correctly, this will display the sum grouped by category;

```
SELECT category, SUM(clicks) AS clicks 
FROM wp_cb_ads_manager 
GROUP BY category
```

Comment: Thank You! Worked like a charm. Still learning mysql, if i want to sum also one more data like impressions, should i just do:

... SUM(clicks) AS clicks, SUM(impressions) AS 'impressions' FROM....

Comment: @GoranJakovljevic Yes, as long as you want to group them all by the same thing (ie category) that will work well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT SUM(clicks) AS 'clicks', count(*), category  FROM wp_cb_ads_manager group by category
```

It works perfectly.

Refer to this

[MySQL SUM when using GROUP BY not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274482/mysql-sum-when-using-group-by-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by group by statement

```
SELECT SUM(clicks) AS 'clicks', category FROM wp_cb_ads_manager group by category
```

Your result set will have sum of clicks against each catrgoty

```
  clicks   | category
    3      |  goan
    5      |  roan
    8      |  mone
```

and so on.